# Black Screen appears when trying to replace the body of Scaffold when click Drawer items list

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to replace the body when click item from drawer list but shows a black screen as the below GIF:

[image]

I have the following below `main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

import 'package:ipet/ui/widgets/ipet_elevated_btn.dart';
import 'package:ipet/ui/widgets/ipet_gesture_detector.dart';
import 'package:ipet/ui/widgets/ipet_icon.dart';
import 'package:ipet/ui/widgets/ipet_list_tile.dart';
import 'package:ipet/ui/widgets/label.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final value = StateProvider<double>((ref) => 0);
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  Color contentColor = Colors.blue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build');
    return Consumer(
      builder: (context, watch, child) => Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    Colors.blue[400],
                    Colors.blue[800],
                  ],
                  begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  end: Alignment.topCenter,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SafeArea(
              child: Container(
                width: 200.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    DrawerHeader(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 50.0,
                            backgroundImage:
                                AssetImage("assets/images/myimage.jpg"),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10.0,
                          ),
                          FittedBox(
                            child: IPetLabel(
                              ipetText: 'Mahmoud Al-Haroon',
                              ipetTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListView(
                        children: [
                          ListTile(
                            onTap: () {
                              contentColor = Colors.blue;
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                            leading: Icon(
                              Icons.home,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            title: IPetLabel(
                              ipetText: 'Home',
                              ipetTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            onTap: () {},
                            leading: Icon(
                              Icons.map,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            title: IPetLabel(
                              ipetText: 'Map',
                              ipetTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          IPetListTile(
                            ltOnTab: () {
                              contentColor = Colors.red;
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                            ltLeading: Icon(
                              Icons.settings,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            ltTitle: IPetLabel(
                              ipetText: 'Settings',
                              ipetTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          IPetListTile(
                            ltOnTab: () {},
                            ltLeading: Icon(
                              Icons.star_rate,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            ltTitle: IPetLabel(
                              ipetText: 'Rate App',
                              ipetTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          IPetListTile(
                            ltOnTab: () {},
                            ltLeading: Icon(
                              Icons.logout,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            ltTitle: IPetLabel(
                              ipetText: 'Logout',
                              ipetTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            TweenAnimationBuilder(
              tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: watch(value).state),
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              curve: Curves.easeIn,
              builder: (_, double val, __) {
                return (Transform(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  transform: Matrix4.identity()
                    ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
                    ..setEntry(0, 3, 200 * val)
                    ..rotateY((pi / 6) * val),
                  child: Scaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(
                      leading: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          watch(value).state == 0
                              ? watch(value).state = 1
                              : watch(value).state = 0;
                        },
                        icon: IPetIcon(
                          ipetIcon: Icons.list,
                          ipetIconColor: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      title: IPetLabel(ipetText: 'IPet'),
                    ),
                    body: Container(
                      color: contentColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ));
              },
            ),
            IPetGestureDetector(
              gdOnHorizontalDragUpdate: (e) {
                if (e.delta.dx > 0) {
                  watch(value).state = 1;
                } else {
                  watch(value).state = 0;
                }
                print(e.delta.dx);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So what I need when click any item from the `Drawer list` I want to change the body only, for example when click settings screen just replace the body only.

Comment: You should not declare (non-static) providers in Widgets. Declare them globally instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please use default app drawer:

```
ScafFold(
 drawer: , // Your List
);
```

Comment: thanks for your support, but this will not work with my recommended drawer

Comment: you can check my answer I have solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Navigator.pop(context);` use `Navigator.of(context).maybePop();` and add this line

```
watch(value).state = 0;
```

[image]